# Array recursive algorithm to rotate values until all values matches a reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, rotation, match

First sorry but I can't think of a better name to describe this exercise/problem.

I already solved this so i'm not really here asking for help but I'm sure it can be perfected a lot and you guys are so talented and challenge lovers I'm sure you will solve this one in a much better way than the one i've done.

So there is the problem:

Given a array of int **valuesToMatch** of any size, as:

```
const valuesToMatch = [-1, -1, 4, -1, 4]
```

And another 2D array **rotatingSliders** containing arrays of int, all of the same size, and with a len >= of **valuesToMatch**

```
 const rotatingSliders = [
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]
      [0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 ]
```

The goal is to find the correct index offset for all arrays in **rotatingSliders** so when you align all arrays, the total of all values at the specified index+offset == the value in the same index in **valuesToMatch**.

value -1 in **valuesToMatch** means you don't care about this index/column.

Get a 2D result array **offsets** containing all possible results, if any.

example with the above arrays, there's only one correct solution so the result should be :

```
offsets = [ [-1, 1] ]
```

Because if you want to align all arrays:

```
[-1, -1,  4, -1,  4]
[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  3]
[ 0,  3,  0,  1,  0,  0]
```

you need to offest the first one in **rotatingSliders** by -1, and the second one by +1:

```
              |       |
    [-1, -1,  4, -1,  4]
[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  3] // offset -1
        [ 0,  3,  0,  1,  0,  0] // offset +1
```

As you can see now:

```
valuesToMatch[3] == 4 && valuesToMatch[5] == 4

rotatingSliders[0][3] + rotatingSliders[1][1] = 1 + 3 = 4

rotatingSliders[1][5] + rotatingSliders[1][3] = 3 + 1 = 4
```

**Note:** values in rotatingSliders arrays are rotating, which means that if the offset push one value offbound, the value is push / shift in the other side of the array.

```
offset -1 means value are shited by 1 index to the left
[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  3] // original
[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  3,  0] // offset - 1

and offset +1 means value are shited 1 index to the right
[ 0,  3,  0,  1,  0,  0] // original
[ 0,  0,  3,  0,  1,  0] // offset + 1
```

The reason for the rule:

> each rotatingSliders len >= of **valuesToMatch** len

Is to ensure that all rotatingSliders have always values aligned with the valuesToMatch array.

And voila, hope you'll enjoy this little challenge :)

[my current solution with some test cases](https://jsfiddle.net/7vjq5mc9/79/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It's great that you found a solution you like.  The norm here is to share your work, whether you've solved it completely and want to compare techniques or you feel as though you're almost there if not for one pesky case or your attempts seem to be going nowhere.  Share your version and people will be more likely to respond.  It also will stop anyone from suspecting that "I've already solved it and want to see your approach" is code for "Please do my homework for me."

Comment: Alright, I edited to add a link to my current solution

Answer (score 0):

(First a side note: Of course I did suspect that this was a homework problem.  Homework problems are acceptable on StackOverflow, but they should be clearly identified as such.  Seeing your work makes many of us much more willing to help.  Sometimes that takes the form of reviewing your code and finding where it's broken.  Sometimes it involves simply offering an alternate approach.  Next time (or even this time) it's much preferred to include the relevant code here and not just a link to it; it doesn't have to include everything; your testing infrastructure is not really relevant.  But all the core code should be included, ideally in a snippet.

---

I don't know if there are clever algorithms to solve this.  But a brute-force version is not too hard to implement.  I build the one below on several helper functions I have laying around: **`range`** create a range of integers, so that, for instance `range (3, 8) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.  **`sum`** simply totals a list of numbers: `sum ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]) //=> 38`, and **`cartesian`** calculates the cartesian product of an array of arrays.  For instance

```js
cartesian ([['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3], ['x', 'y']]) 
//=> [['a', 1', 'x'], ['a', 1, 'y'], ['a', 2, 'x'], ... ['b', 3, 'y']]
```

Using these, we can find the range of possible offsets for each slider, take the cartesian product of those results, and then search through the possible offsets for the first one where each of the relevant values matches the sum of the offsetted values from the sliders.  It looks like this:

```js
const slideToMatch = (values, sliders) => 
  cartesian (sliders .map (s => rng (- s .length, s .length)))
    .find (offsets => values .every (
      (v, i) => v == -1 || v == sum (
        sliders .map ((slider, j) => slider [i - offsets[j]])
      )
    ))
```

One advantage of this is that if we don't just want to find *one* possibility but instead find *all* of them, we can just replace `find` with `filter`.

There is almost certainly some optimization possible for this.  I'm choosing a very naïve range here, moving the slider along its entire length.  There is certainly a more clever version that uses the positions of the non-`-1` values in the target array to control the ranges.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader, though.

I also want to note that the input structure, with the `-1`s noting the positions we can ignore is to my mind suboptimal.  I think any of these would be cleaner:

```
  const values = {2: 4, 4: 4}
  // or
  const values = [{index: 2, value: 4}, {index: 4, value: 4}]
  // or
  const values = [[2, 4], [4, 4]]
```

all of which would be easily to work into that function.

Here is what it all looks like together with the helper functions:

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs = undefined
    ? []
  : xss.length == 0
    ? xs .map (x => [x])
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))
const range = (lo, hi) => 
  [...Array (hi - lo + 1)] .map ((_, i) => lo + i)
const sum = (ns) => 
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const slideToMatch = (values, sliders) => 
  cartesian (sliders .map (s => range (- s .length, s .length)))
    .find (offsets => values .every (
      (v, i) => v == -1 || v == sum (
        sliders .map ((slider, j) => slider [i - offsets[j]])
      )
    ))

console .log (slideToMatch (
  [-1, -1, 4, -1, 4], 
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
    [0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  ]
))

console .log ( slideToMatch (
  [-1, -1, 4, -1, 4], 
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
    [0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1],
  ]
))
```